# 14.04 disk mount problem came our of left field

Tags: mount, disk, partitioning

So I have a partition that I use to backup/store things. This partition worked correctly since I installed 14.04 with no problems.

Now all of a sudden I am gettting errors saying I am running out of disk space (not likely '/' = 25gb '/home' = 50gb) and they are lightly used (a few gb's at the most)

The problem I found is that one of my partitions is having mounting issues and somehow being calculated as part of the root drive.

If I try to unmount that drive in nautilus, I get...

```
Error unmounting /dev/sda7: Command-line `umount  "/media/jeff/52244CCF244CB82D"'      
exited with non-zero exit status 1: umount: /media/jeff/52244CCF244CB82D: not mounted
```

I have no idea what could be causing this or when it actually started. Any ideas?

AS REQUESTED:
/etc/fstab....

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=828a5223-2197-404b-872e-6b8065a6fe71 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=9A00-3A00  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=7fc431e9-d150-4bb9-a9b2-d90eb7289bc9 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda11 during installation
UUID=2070661b-2eba-4d94-b67b-69e6b786b980 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

$ blk /dev/sda7

```
/dev/sda7: UUID="52244CCF244CB82D" TYPE="ntfs"
```

ADDDED:

```
/dev/sda8 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
overflow on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,size=1048576,mode=1777)
/dev/sda9 on /home type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda3 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=jeff)
```

WHAT I THINK IS HAPPENING...

1. Something happened that caused an error with the mounted drive
2. it is now being prevented from doing anything, in a sort of locked state
3. When I go into nautilus and click on the drive itself, it mounts itself with a '1' appended to the end of the drive. If I go to /media/jeff I see both drives, one with an x over it, that is empty, ...and one that is normal.
4. If I go to the terminal and try to mount/unmount the '+1' drive it works
5. If I go to terminal and try to mount/unmount the drive with the 'x' it fails

So it is sort of stuck somehow and it is also jamming up my root drive space somehow. What would happen if I just did '$ sudo rm /media/jeff/stuckdrive'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you considered your /home partition never got automounted (at least it does not now). So Ubuntu still includes the /home directory to the root partition /. And of course, as it does not get mounted at boot time, you can  not manually unmount it either!

So I suppose we have to manually edit your /etc/fstab configuration file. Could you please post this by including it into your question? You can leave the first 6 lines out and start with the line beginning with "# 
We might also need the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sda7` to add this partition back to your automount list.

So when you attached those two pieces of information to your post, just leave me a short comment on this answer to wake me up... ;D
See you later!

CORRECTION: It is not the /home partition that fails but an independent NTFS backup volume! I misunderstood.

Comment: Ummm, you're sure that /dev/sda7 used to be your /home partition? It is formatted in NTFS, while fstab says it was on sda9 and had ext4???

Comment: no, maybe I wasn't clear, my home partition is fine. This is a separate partition that I used to run some automatic backups of things, and backup windows as well. just a storage partition. So this other partition (not home, not root) is somehow filling up root to its capacity before it tells me it is out of space. (the partition is bigger than root)

Comment: Something to note. If I go into /media/jeff this is what I see for that drive http://imgur.com/e0qlukc the one with the '1' appended to the end I can open and view, while the one with the regular name is empty and has that red x over it. Something also just came to mind. I lost power the other day, and it is possible that the computer was mid-backup via a cronjob. Maybe it screwed something up that way?

Comment: You know that every partition Linux mounts gets inserted into the root file system (usually at /mnt/... or /dev/...)? So we have to keep the physical partition (sda8?) and the file system root "/" apart. After this, do you have problems mounting the backup partition? And if yes, how did you try to mount it?

Comment: Okay, the comment above was posted before I read your last one. The red X usually says that you don't have enough rights to enter this directory. So how did you mount it?

Comment: I didn't do anything particular to mount it. Usually it gets mounted automatically, or by me going through nautilus and clicking on the drive. My other partitions still mount/unmount this way

Comment: I read your question again and again, but it does not really become clearer to me. Could you please add the output of `mount -l` to your post? It shows all currently mounted file systems. (Don't be shocked on the big number, there are many virtual file systems too!)

Comment: added, it doesn't make sense to me either, sorry :( thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you check whether the output of `mount` differs from the output of `sudo mount`? Are there any additional lines?

Comment: they are identical. I added a little breakdown of the problem to my post, because it is becoming a little convoluted.

Comment: I'm not sure about deleting the mountpoint. I would better not risk this without a backup! Have you ever rebooted since this error occurred first?

Comment: yes, rebooted, logged out, hibernated, booted windows, the works

Comment: No idea. Maybe you could just copy all your data and try ereasing the mountpoint (with sudo, I think). I should better get some sleep before thinking much more about this issue. It's 4am here...

Comment: well thanks for all your brainpower, ill let you know if I solve it

Comment: I deleted the mount point and everything went fine, the drive is still there and mounts correctly now with all filed intact. If you add the solution to your main post, I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks EDIT: NVM, i did it for you. thanks

Comment: Great! Now I can sleep just fine. The simplest solutions are always the best. Greetings and good bye :)